# Install Android studio on external ssd on Mackbook air m1

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

i have recently bought a macBook air m1 (16gb ram 256gb ssd ) ,
in order to keep my 256gb internal ssd less bloated

1. can i install android studio on my external ssd(samsung T7)
2. and are there any issue that i can face while doing this?
   or any tips in general related to what i am trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install in external drive. But you might experience a delay or stutter while running your code on emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install apps on an external drive. Speed might be a little less, but not very significant. There are a few steps need to be followed though.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq-Wc7su0YY
You can refer to this video.
Have a great day.!